# How to validate an angular form after submit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I need to design a form using angularjs. I need to use two kind of validation,

1. When a user fills the form , I need to validate that field on fly.This is by default.
2. I do not want to disable the submit button. Lets say if a user comes to the page and directly clicks on the submit button,
   then also I want to show all the error on different fields.How this can be done . I have tried using $setValidity() But not successful.How this can be done.

This is the form.

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

sampleApp.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.userData = {

      fname: "",
      lname: ""
    };


    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submitForm = function(registrationForm) {
      $scope.registrationForm.fname.$dirty = true;
   $scope.registrationForm.lname.$dirty = true;
      if (registrationForm.$invalid) {
        alert("form validation error.");
        return;
      } else {
        alert("form submitted successfully.");
      }

    }
  }
]);
```

```css
input.ng-invalid {
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
   input.ng-valid {
     border: 1px solid green;
   }
   input.ng-pristine { 
    border-color: #FFFF00;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<body ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
  <form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="submitForm(registrationForm)" novalidate>
    FirstName*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="userData.fname" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span ng-show="registrationForm.fname.$dirty && registrationForm.fname.$error.required">
    First name is required.
   </span>

    <br>LastName*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="userData.lname" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span ng-show="registrationForm.lname.$dirty && registrationForm.lname.$error.required">
    Last name is required.
   </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may use $scope.myForm.$setDirty(); to achieve this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to make your form validations show up upon form submission, you can just set the `$scope.registrationForm.lname.$dirty = true;` and `$scope.registrationForm.fname.$dirty = true;` in your `$scope.submitForm` function.

Solution:

```js
var sampleApp = angular.module("sampleApp", []);
sampleApp.controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.userData = {
      fname: "",
      lname: ""
    };
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submitForm = function(registrationForm) {
      if (registrationForm.$invalid) {
        alert("form validation error.");
        $scope.registrationForm.lname.$dirty = true;
        $scope.registrationForm.fname.$dirty = true;
        return;
      } else {
        alert("form submitted successfully.");
      }

    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<html ng-app="sampleApp">

<body ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
  <form name="registrationForm" ng-submit="submitForm(registrationForm)" novalidate>
    FirstName*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="userData.fname" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span ng-show="registrationForm.fname.$dirty && registrationForm.fname.$error.required">First name is required.</span>
    <br>LastName*
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="userData.lname" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span ng-show="registrationForm.lname.$dirty && registrationForm.lname.$error.required">Last name is required.</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```